# How does Mac OS X know what programs are using a mounted filesystem?

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard, stat, unmount

This may sound like a silly question but up until recently if you tried to unmount a volume that was in use the Finder reported that it was in use, but not by whom.  This is simple Unix functionality, if a file is open on a mount point, do not allow it to eject.  But now they seem to have added functionality that lets the user know what programs are currently using a mounted system, and I have been looking through man pages of fopen,stat, etc. for Unix like operating systems(distros of linux) and I can't seem to find similar functionality.

Is this functionality specialized, or am I just looking in the wrong place?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are BSD-level calls (mainly `lsof`, whose source is at http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/lsof/) that let you examine the list of files open in a process. Activity Monitor, for example, uses them.

Using `lsof` as a starting point, you can iterate through processes and see if any of them are using a file under the mount point you're examining. There may be more efficient ways to do it though, of which I'm not aware. :)

Comment: Lsof revision 4.82 lists on its standard output file information about files opened by processes for the following UNIX dialects:

            AIX 5.3
            FreeBSD 4.9 for x86-based systems
            FreeBSD 7.[01] and 8.0 for AMD64-based systems
            Linux 2.1.72 and above for x86-based systems
            Mac OS X 10.[56] for Intel and PowerPC systems
            Solaris 9 and 10

Comment: Okay? Sounds like you're covered.

Answer (score 0):

It's somewhat specialized. Check out the `lsof` utility.

Answer (score 0):

Check the man page for `fuser`, and run `fuser -c /mountpoint`